# PHP Local Host and Server give different result using dateTime function

Tags: php, datetime

The following code produces different results depending on where its running.

```
function convert( $timestamp, $timezone ){
  $obj = new DateTimeImmutable( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp ), new DateTimeZone( "UTC" ));
  return $obj->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( $timezone ));
}
echo convert( 1644153296, "America/Chicago" )->format( "Y-m-d g:i a T" );
```

2022-02-06 7:14 am CST on local

2022-02-06 2:14 am CST on server

So my question is why? or actually how do I fix this?

Comment: Set the overall timezone with [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Comment: Thank you. date_default_timezone_set('UTC') at top of script worked. Counter intuitive to me since I created a dateTime with UTC timezone.